# How can I log out?

Tags: feature-request

My brother has opened an account at this wonderful site, I heard it is allowed to have different accounts, as long as you do not interact and do not upvote each other.
Can you confirm this is perfectly OK?

If, so can you tell me how to log out? I can't find a button

Comment: In the upper left hand corner of this page there is a StackExchange logo, click on it, and on the upper right hand corner of the drop down you will see the words log out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having two accounts from the same household is fine. In fact, you *can* vote on each other's posts if you come across them, but you should be sure to vote only based on content, not based on who made the post. And you shouldn't intentionally look for each other's posts. This is covered in [What is the procedure for having my spouse/significant other as a member of the same SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175374/what-is-the-procedure-for-having-my-spouse-significant-other-as-a-member-of-the) If you're worried about being impartial, then just don't vote on each other's posts at all.

In fact, even one person *can* have multiple accounts. In this case the connection should probably be disclosed, and the accounts most certainly should not vote for each other. I've seen this done where, for instance, a high-rep user or moderator wants a less-privileged account to *suggest* edits or closures, rather than *force* them.

As for logging out, look to the top bar, on the left:

[image: first click]

There is a logout option in the menu:

[image: second click]

Comment: By the way, writing this made me realize I probably haven't logged out in years.

Comment: [_You can check-out any time you like,
But you can never leave!_](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=eagles+hotel+california+lyrics)